# All variables of particular column to a single list

Tags: python

I need help converting variables of one column into one list. When I tried myself I got output as a list of lists, but I need one list.

My column looks like this:

```
30% down payment

Limited Units , 3 Yrs Payment Plan , La Violeta TH

OPEN HOUSE, FEB 25-26 , Motivated Seller

Bright and Spacious Apt , Serene Location

Exclusive , Affordable Options Available
```

Here is my code:

```
title=dataset['title']
flat_title_list=[]
for lists in title:
   flat_title_list.append(lists)
   flat_title_list
```

Here is the output I got:

```
['30% down payment',
 'Limited Units , 3 Yrs Payment Plan , La Violeta TH',
 'OPEN HOUSE, FEB 25-26 , Motivated Seller',
 'Bright and Spacious Apt , Serene Location',
 'Exclusive , Affordable Options Available']
```

However, I want it to look like this:

```
['30% down payment',
 'Limited Units', '3 Yrs Payment Plan' , 'La Violeta TH',
 'OPEN HOUSE', 'FEB 25-26' , 'Motivated Seller',
 'Bright and Spacious Apt' , 'Serene Location',
 'Exclusive' , 'Affordable Options Available']
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the difference here ?

Comment: pay attention to quotes

Comment: Do you want to split on comma? Something like `[item for record in dataset['title'] for item in record.split(' , ')]`

Answer (score 0):

You might try to flatten the inner list of lists by nesting another for loop, e.g. something like that:

```
title=dataset['title']
flat_title_list=[]
for lists in title:
   for inner_list in lists:
       flat_title_list.append(inner_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need split on commas something like this should work:

```py
[item for record in dataset['title'] for item in record.split(' , ')]
```